# Is there a larger $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$ than $2^{\Omega}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I came across a question in the excellent measure theory textbook "Probability and Measure" by Patrick Billinglsey (1995, Q2.10) that asks;

(i) If $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ contains every subset of $\Omega$ then for each pair $\omega,\omega'\in\Omega$ where $\omega\not=\omega$ there exists a $A\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $1_{A}(\omega)\not=1_{A}(\omega')$

(ii) Show the reverse implication holds if $\Omega$ is countable

My question does not pertain to the substance of the question, which is to say the conditions under which the separating set $A$ exists (although I find this idea very interesting and have been studying it), but rather my question is about the implication of the hypothesis in (i) that $2^{\Omega}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

The class $\mathcal{A}$ is an arbitrary class of subsets of $\Omega$, i.e. no structure or properties are assumed such as the class being a field or a $\sigma$-field. From various questions on this site regarding the power set $2^{\Omega}$ I see agreement that it is not only a $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$, but the largest possible $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$. So surely if $2^{\Omega}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ then in fact we must conclude $2^{\Omega}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$? I believe I can even prove this: $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and $\mathcal{A}\subseteq 2^{\Omega}$ together imply $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A})\subseteq 2^{\Omega}$ since by definition $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the smallest possible $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$ containing $\mathcal{A}$. Accordingly the hypothesis in (i) of $2^{\Omega}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ gives $2^{\Omega}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ as claimed?

This all seems correct but I am having a moment of self-doubt: why would Billinglsey put $2^{\Omega}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ since he did not make his name as such a great expositor of probability theory by stating superfluous things - I would have assumed he would have stated $2^{\Omega}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ if there really is no chance that $2^{\Omega}\subset\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ could be true? Am I overthinking this and Billingsley simply invites us to prove $2^{\Omega}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ as an extra challenge, or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: If $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ then trivially $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ as $\sigma(\mathcal{A})\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ *by definition*

Comment: Thanks! So I am not mistaken? I like the simple proof.

Comment: You proof works, but even simpler is noticing that *any* $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ by definition